# Why isn't ReactRedux defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs, redux

I am using webpack and babel. I have a file like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactRedux from 'react-redux';

var Layout = React.createClass({
  render(){
    return (<div>Markup</div>);
  }
});


function mapStateToProps(state, action) {
  return state;
}

export default ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps)(Layout);
```

For some reason when I run webpack, after compiling, it runs with this error: `Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined`. Not sure why it would fail at getting ReactRedux object. My webpack config is like this:

```
var compiler = webpack({
    entry: "./dist/runner.js",
    module: {
      loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
          loader: 'babel', // 'babel-loader' is also a legal name to reference
          query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
      filename: "public/dist/bundle.js"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because the react-redux package doesn't have a default export on the module.  You can access the connect function manually like:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
```

...

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Layout);
```

Comment: Or, alternatively, `import * as ReactRedux from 'react-redux';`

Comment: Yes, I realized that shortly after posting! :)

Comment: PS: I had just converted from `require` to `import` which is why I was extra confused that same code stopped working